# How to edit existing Pie chart option in google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, pie-chart

Hello respective members,
I need to edit colour options for an existing pie chart in google sheet. I don't know how to open this option in Apps Script. I want to change the pie to a half-circle.
The pie chart was created from the Insert menu and I choose the chart. Not by Apps Script.
So is it possible to use Apps Script to edit it?
Thank you in advance.
Greetings.

Answer (score 0):

In Apps Script you can use the SpreadsheetApp's [`EmbeddedChart`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/embedded-chart) class which allows you to to modify an existing chart.